# Static code analysis for Free Pascal

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, static-code-analysis

Are there any tools available that allow static code analysis for Free Pascal sources? I would prefer a solution that allows for checking a whole Lazarus project.

Comment: I am is great code analisys tool. Hope you are provide some specific question. Ok, without jikes, Lazarud hve two independed log tools: [first](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:Event_Log) There are a lot of other tools to debug your app. Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

*Static code analysis* is a general *technic*, not a tool in itself.

the Lazarus IDE contains at least two tools based on *static analysis*:

- the code explorer (symbol list):

[image: code explorer]

- the quick syntax checker: Menu, Source: quick syntax check

[image]

(this is what is commonly named a linter). But these tools are not available as standalone application.

Comment: Yes, these are nice tools that are provided by the Lazarus IDE. My requirements are a bit more, however. The tool should also find bugs that are beyond the pure syntactical layer, e.g. unnecessarily complex or inefficient code, bad coding style and duplicate code resulting from copy and paste. I would like to implement NASA’s 10 rules for developing safety-critical code, which requires static code analysis,

Comment: I've you've post the same Q. in the official board. You've been more accurate over there than here.